# HockeyApp launch my app and make it behave differently. What's the cause (how to debug)?

Tags: android, continuous-integration, hockeyapp

I have an Android app, when I compile and run works fine. Part of the CI process, we uses HockeyApp for our tester to download the App.

When the App is downloaded by HockeyApp and Launched directly, the behavior of the App differs from when I compile and run it.

If I just download and install from HockeyApp, and instead of launch it directly (e.g. the HockeyApp will ask if we want to launch it), I click DONE and then manually launch it, the App behaves normal.

I don't know where to start debug such issue... and why HockeyApp could cause different behavior if we use it to launch. Perhaps this is not a real issue, as when we install from GooglePlay and launch it, it shouldn't have the problem... but I'm not fully sure.

Any guide how should I start debugging the issue?

p/s: Just to add on, the different behavior is, the set value (selected TAB on TABBAR) doesn't stays persistent. It reset to it's initial value when we go to background and come back. This happens even if DON'T KEEP ACTIVITY is OFF. Note: in normal behavior, the value is persist, and stored it properly using SavedInstanceState i.e. even when we have DON"T KEEP ACTIVITY, it persists on without any issue.

Comment: do u solve this problem? I have same problem on my project :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm the developer of the HockeyApp app for Android. Can you post screenshots on how the app behaves differently when you launch it after installed through HockeyApp than through your IDE? This was not really clear to me from your post.

Feel free to open a [support request](http://support.hockeyapp.net), where you can also post screenshots explaining the issue. I will make sure to handle this directly.

Some background: HockeyApp only downloads the APK. Once the download is completed, the APK is handed over to the Android package manager, which is taking care of installation and launching the app. This is the only way how non-system apps can install APKs on Android.

Comment: Thanks Matthias. Unfortunately this is a commercial product, and I can't post anything prior to it's release. Anyway, the issue is as below. Normal launch, the App would be able to have it's state save, when it goes background and foreground, the clicked setting remains (e.g. tab). However, using HockeyApp to launch, it works fine after launch. But one we put it to background and bring to foreground, it reset all the setting, and resume the initial value (e.g. the tab went back to original position). This is the odd behavior faced.

Comment: Perhaps you could advice, other than using HockeyApp to launch, is there other way to emulate how HockeyApp launch the App, but not using HockeyApp? Note, I tried using adb install the app, and then launch it, or I launch it directly using Android Studio, all works fine.

Comment: Can you tell us on what device and Android version you run into this problem? Otherwise this sounds like an odd thing to debug, and we can't reproduce it without at least some sample code. You can create private support requests, we will not share your confidential information with anyone.

Comment: We have tested it on multiple devices (Nexus, Sony, Samsung) and it is consistent and across different version of Android (4.4, 5.0). If I do have the chance to shrink it down to something easily share, then I'll post it for you.